# Reading InputStream to Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, inputstream

I have to read a dict.txt file which contains one string for line and add these to an arraylist.

I tried this:

```
public ArrayList<String> myDict = new ArrayList<String>();

InputStream is = (getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.dict));
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
try {
    while (r.readLine() != null) {
        myDict.add(r.readLine());
    }  
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

but something wrong...

Comment: you are reading two times one in while and second time while adding to list.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are iterating twice in each loop

```
String line;
while ((line=r.readLine()) != null) {
    myDict.add(line);
}
```

Comment: Should the "line" variable in your response be of type ArrayList?

Answer (score 19):

Using Apache IOUtils:

```
List<String> lines = IOUtils.readLines(inputStream, "UTF-8");
```